# Why this conditional does not raise an Exception: (1==0 <= 1/0) == False? How Python parses this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

How come this is evaluate to `False`?

`1==0 <= 1/0`

First note that in Python:

`bols = [False, True]
for A in bols:
    for B in bols:
        print(f'{str(A):>5}, {str(B):>5}, {str(A<=B):>5}')`

Outputs:

`False, False,  True
False,  True,  True
 True, False, False
 True,  True,  True`

If you are familiar with boolean logic this hould be natural to you.

Now it gets weird:

`print(1==1 <= 1/1, 1==0 <= 1/1)`

Out: `True, False`

And now it gets weirder:

`print(1==0 <= 1/0)`

Out: `False`

Why this last one does not throw an exeption?

My first guess is becasue of parsing issues. 
For example, a previous comparasion we can fix adding parenthesis:

`print(1==1 <= 1/1,  (1==0) <= 1/1)`

Out: `True, True`

But if this issue is a parsing problem, how come python does not raise an exception when we divide by 0?

If we add parenthesis to the last comparasion we can force Python to raise ZeroDivision Exeption:

`print((1==0) <= 1/0)`

Out: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

Also, why the following raises an Exception?

`1==1 <= 1/0`

Out: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`

NB: This works with other exceptions as well, probably with any, since python does not evaluate the right hand side of the inequality.

Why?

I would understand if the laizy evaluation were `True`, but why `False`? Feels like a bug in Python.

Answer (score 7):

#### 1==0 <= 1/0

`1/0` is never evaluated. The expression triggers chained comparison in Python. It is evaluated as:

```
(1 == 0) and (0 <= 1/0)
```

Logical `and` short-circuits when a `False` value is reached, so the second condition is never tested. Since `1 == 0` evaluates to `False`, the result is `False`.

---

#### 1==1 <= 1/0

In the same vein, this is evaluated as:

```
(1 == 1) and (1 <= 1/0)
```

Since the first expression is `True`, the second one is evaluated. This leads to `ZeroDivisionError`.

---

#### (1==0) <= 1/0

Parentheses have higher priority than comparison operators. So chained comparisons are not triggered here. The expression is evaluated as `False <= 1/0`. Of course, the comparison will fail with `ZeroDivisionError`.

---

#### 1==1 <= 1/1, 1==0 <= 1/1

Here you are defining a `tuple` of results. A tuple is implicit by the existence of a comma separating your two expressions. The first, `1==1 <= 1/1`, evaluates to `True` since `True <= 1`. The second, `1==0 <= 1/1`, evaluates to `True` since `False <= 1`.

These comparisons work since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` is equivalent to `0`.

Comment: But like I said in the beginning, everytime False in in the left hand side of the inequality, it outputs True, why in this case is False?

Comment: `everytime False in in the left hand side of the inequality, it outputs True`. This example demonstrates the opposite of your statement. The left hand side evaluates to `False`, so the result is `False`.

Comment: Yes, of course this example shows the opposite of my statement, that is why it was so puzzingly. 
Anyway, with yoyur explanation I understood what is going on. Thanks

Comment: @zeh, If you found this answer helpful, do consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it (green tick on left).

Comment: @zeh, Unfortunately some reviewers already declined them (not me). I've incorporated some of the changes you suggested.